# jQuery using .find() can't get width of dynamically appended element

Tags: jquery, html

I have the following code:

**HTML:**

```
<button class="button">Click this!</button>
<div id="divInDom">Div already in DOM.</div>
```

**JS:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var myStuff = {
    elements: {
        divInDom: $(document).find('#divInDom'),
        divAppended: $(document).find('#divAppended')
    }
}

$(document.body).on('click', '.button', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();

    $('body').append('<div id="divAppended">Div that just got appended.</div>');

    var a = myStuff.elements.divInDom.outerWidth();
    var b = myStuff.elements.divAppended.outerWidth();

    alert('Width of div that was already in DOM: ' + a);
    alert('Width of div that just got appended: ' + b);

});
});
```

Live sample: http://jsfiddle.net/uq62zz9h/

`a` will return the width of the div, while `b` won't.

I may be misusing jQuery in this case, but is it possible to make `b` return the width of the appended `div`, by calling the property from object?

Comment: You're `divAppended` doesn't exist at `$(document).ready()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line `$(document).find('#divAppended')` is returning an empty array since the element doesn't exist at that point.

jQuery already evaluated the selector and found nothing, you'll need to execute that AFTER adding the element.

You can implement `divInDom` and `divAppended` as functions to evaluate the selector on every call.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var myStuff = {
        elements: {
            divInDom: function() {
                return $(document).find('#divInDom');
            },
            divAppended: function() {
                return $(document).find('#divAppended');
            }
        }
    }

    $(document.body).on('click', '.button', function(event){
        event.preventDefault();

        $('body').append('<div id="divAppended">Div that just got appended.</div>');

        var a = myStuff.elements.divInDom().outerWidth();
        var b = myStuff.elements.divAppended().outerWidth();

        alert('Width of div that was already in DOM: ' + a);
        alert('Width of div that just got appended: ' + b);

    });
});
```